# Converting from text field string to double

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently working on a weight tracking app as a tutorial project for Swift. I am implementing the MVVM pattern, and I have a  `weightEntry` class, where one of the attributes is `weight`, a `Double`.

In my view I have one ViewModel object, which has a `weightEntry` object. I would like to assign the entry in the Weight text field to my `weightEntry.weight`, however I'm not sure how I could convert the format from string to double in the view?

Below is the code in the view:

```
    @ObservedObject var mainViewVM = MainViewViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/nil/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, content: {
            
            
            Text("Weight Tracking App").font(.title)
            
            HStack {
                Text("Add your current weight").font(.subheadline)
                TextField("Weight", text: $mainViewVM.weightEntry.weight)
                    .padding()
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a initializer which can take a `Double` and a format description , [`init(_:value:format:prompt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:value:format:prompt:)-7flsn).

```
TextField("Weight", value: $mainViewVM.weightEntry.weight, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(1)))
```